# How to create LocalDB instance programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, localdb

What is the .NET code equivalent of running below command?

```
sqllocaldb c <myInstance>
```

Please note that my question is NOT about creating a localdb **database** programmatically; rather creating an instance programmatically. I am trying to find about creating a new instance so that I can use `(localdb)\myInstance` in my connection string.

**Update**
This is part of installing a desktop product. Creation of instance needs to happen on client machines that install this desktop product. As such, creating it using Visual Studio or SSMS is not the solution I'm looking for.

The closest answer I've gotten is @vasily.sib's `Process.Start()`. If no other option, this is what I will have to go with.

Comment: are you using visual studio IDE?

Comment: I usually create my databases in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as well as my tables.  SSMS explorer you can right click DataBases to create new database.  Then right click Table to create new table and columns.  Once the database is created I can then connect using VS menu to connect to an existing database.

Comment: Maybe `Process.Start("sqllocaldb ", "c <myInstance>")`? It's not a good solution btw. I think you should create DB on deployment step of your application, not at runtime.

Comment: @vasily.sib is the only one coming close to what I asked. Yes! This is during deployment step; as part of Visual Studio Installer project.

Comment: @ChaoticCoder `Please note that my question is NOT about creating a localdb database programmatically` this is an perfect example of when asking a question that you need to use enough specificity and appropriate language to easily portray exactly what you want, what your desired outputs are, what is not working for you, what you have tried, and what you don't understand (the first time) we are total strangers and don't know whats in your head. Anyway good luck, the more information you can add, the more we can help you

Comment: @TheGeneral thank you for pointing out. I've stressed that my question is not about creating database rather creating an instance programmatically.

Comment: There is other options. Look to @BACON link. There are a lot of sqllocaldb native api wrappers. You should look at them first. My `Process.Start()` solution - is easy, but bad solution (like almost any `Process.Start()` solutions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used sqllocaldb package from https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb. It works beautifully for programmatically doing all local db operations.

Comment: Although your answer has been accepted, it's better you provide a minimum usage sample to show that the library is really useful